# Указание падежей для английских слов в русском языке

Tags: грамматика, падежи, английский-язык, латиница-кириллица, апостроф

Как правильнее писать, "отправить по email" или "отправить по email'у" и почему? Использовать русский вариант не хотелось бы, так как "отправить по емейлу" или "по имейлу" звучит очень коряво.

Comment: В общем случае, мне нужно придумать название кнопке, которая бы пересылала документ по какому-либо email'у, и поэтому желательно, чтобы оно было как можно короче.  
В принципе, устроило бы любое альтернативное название для такой функциональности.  
Также, очень здорово было бы узнать, пишутся ли вообще апострофы в русском языке в похожих сценариях.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Либо "по email", либо по электронной почте. Ни к чему к иноязычному слову присобачивать русское окончание, даже через апостроф.

Comment: в общем случае, мне нужно придумать название кнопке, которая бы пересылала документ по какому-либо email'у, и поэтому желательно, чтобы оно было как можно короче. В принципе, устроило бы любое альтернативное название для такой функциональности. Также, очень здорово было бы узнать, пишутся ли вообще апострофы в русском языке в похожих сценариях. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Руководствуясь моим imho'м, я бы написал "отправить электронной почтой". Web'ом.
Хотя бы потому, что не стоит мешать французский с нижегородским. А вот как гласят современные правила, даже не знаю. Пусть другие ответят. Wireless'но...

Answer (score 0):

Нет смысла пытаться склонять в русском английские слова - если хочется оставить в латинице, то подойдёт **по email** (= по эл. почте; дефис практически ушёл из написания).

В русском же "имейл" обычно имеет значение *письма* (распространилось краткое выражение: *пришли мне имейл*), а не эл. *почты*, поэтому "*по имейлу*" и звучит коряво (= "отправить *по письму*"). Соответственно, отправлять сообщение или файл естественнее **имейлом** (= письмом, в виде письма) или (формально) **по электронной почте**.

Comment: мне кажется, что краткое выражение _пришли мне имейл_ нужно затем, **чтобы не говорить что конкретно пересылать  (письмо, фото, файлы)** т. к. обычно эта информация берётся из контекста. А в случае, если такого контекста нет, то всё же правильнее говорить _пересылаю фотки по email'у_, а не _пересылаю фотки email'ом_

Comment: в моём случае мне нужно придумать название кнопке, которая бы пересылала документ по какому-либо email'у, и поэтому желательно, чтобы оно было как можно короче. В принципе, устроило бы любое альтернативное название для такой функциональности. Также, очень здорово было бы узнать, пишутся ли вообще апострофы в русском языке в похожих сценариях.